# Google Map, SVG Graph and ruler

Tags: javascript, jquery, beginner, svg, google-maps

I would like to get feedback on the code. It is working and can be seen [here](http://gedysantraining.azurewebsites.net/svg%20studyV3.html).

I welcome any kind of feedback, since I am just starting to use JavaScript.  Epecially in the case of performance, there might be better ways to code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var latlng, altitude, time, distance;
    var graphDataAlt = []; var graphDataTime = [];
    var showTime = false;
    var margin, svg, ruler, map, marker;

    $.ajax({
        url: "LoadStreams.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "post",
        success: function (data) {
            drawGraph(data);
        }
    });
    //Below the main loop program for all the graph functions
    function drawGraph(data) {
        //TODO: Test on datatypes and set data
        latlng = data[0].data;
        time = data[1].data;
        distance = data[2].data;
        altitude = data[3].data;
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse;
        for (var i = 0; i < distance.length; i++) {
            var obj = {}; var obj1 = {};
            obj.hor = distance[i] / 1000;
            obj1.hor = parseTime(time[i]);
            obj1.hor = parseDate(obj1.hor);
            obj.vert = altitude[i];
            obj1.vert = altitude[i];
            graphDataAlt.push(obj);
            graphDataTime.push(obj1);
        }
        //******************* GOOGLE MAPS *********************
        //set Path and bounds
        var path = [];
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (i = 0; i < latlng.length; i++) {
            var lat = latlng[i][0];
            var lng = latlng[i][1];
            path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
            bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
        }
        //define Map
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 11,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        //define Polyline
        var route = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: path,
            geodesic: false,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });
        //Set Bounds
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        //Show route on the map
        route.setMap(map);
        //Define the marker
        var image = {
            url: 'cycling.png'
        };
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: image
        });
        //********************** SVG ***************************************
        showGraph(graphDataAlt);
        //TODO define the eventhandlers for moving the ruler and markers
        // Toggle de data voor de graph
        $("#test").on("click", function () {
            showTime = !showTime;
            if (showTime) { $("#test").text("Distance"); updateGraph(graphDataTime, showTime); }
            else { $("#test").text("Time"); updateGraph(graphDataAlt, showTime); }
        });
        var svg = d3.select("#graph1");
        var ruler = d3.select(".ruler");
        svg.select("#grid")
                .on("mouseout", function () { ruler.style("display", "none"); marker.setMap(null); })
                .on("mousemove", mousemove)
                ;
        function mousemove() {
            x = d3.mouse(this)[0];
            ruler.style("display", null); marker.setMap(map);
            ruler.attr("transform", "translate(" + x + ", 0)");
            var latlng = path[Math.floor((x / width) * path.length)];
            marker.setPosition(latlng);
        }

    }; //drawGraph

    var margin = { top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
                 width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
                 height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    function updateGraph(data, showTime) {
        if (!showTime) {
            var x = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([0, width])
                .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.hor; })]);
        }
        else {
            var x = d3.time.scale()
                .range([0, width])
                .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.hor; }));
        }
        var max = d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.vert; });
        var min = d3.min(data, function (d) { return d.vert; });
        if (max < 50) { max = 200; }
        if (min < -5) { min = -50; }
        var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .rangeRound([height, 0])
                .domain([min, max]);

        function make_x_axis() {
            return d3.svg.axis()
                 .scale(x)
                 .orient("bottom")
                 .ticks(10)
        }

        var svg = d3.select("#graph1");

        svg.select("g.grid")
                .call(make_x_axis()
                     .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
                     .tickFormat("")
                );
        //Update Area
        var area = d3.svg.area()
                 .x(function (d) { return x(d.hor); })
                 .y0(height)
                 .y1(function (d) { return y(d.vert); });

        svg.select("path.area")
                 .datum([data])
                 .attr("d", area(data));

        var valueline = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function (d) { return x(d.hor); })
                .y(function (d) { return y(d.vert); });

        svg.select("path.line")
                .data([data])
                .attr("d", valueline(data));


        //Update x axis
        if (showTime) {
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
                 .orient("bottom").ticks(11)
                 .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S"));
        }
        else {
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
                 .orient("bottom").ticks(10);
        }

        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%X").parse;
        svg.select(".x.axis")
                 .data([data])
                 .call(xAxis)
                 .selectAll("text").text(function (d, i) { if (showTime) { return parseDate(d.hor) } else { return d = d + '.0 km' } });
    }

    function showGraph(data) {
        var x = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([0, width])
                .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.hor; })]);
        var max = d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.vert; });
        var min = d3.min(data, function (d) { return d.vert; });
        if (max < 50) { max = 200; }
        if (min < -5) { min = -50; }
        var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .rangeRound([height, 0])
                .domain([min, max]);
        // Define Axis
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
                 .orient("bottom").ticks(10);

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
                 .orient("left").ticks(4);

        var valueline = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function (d) { return x(d.hor); })
                .y(function (d) { return y(d.vert); });
        // Define Area
        var area = d3.svg.area()
             .x(function (d) { return x(d.hor); })
             .y0(height)
             .y1(function (d) { return y(d.vert); });

        var svg = d3.select("#graph1")
                 .append("svg")
                     .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                     .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                 .append("g")
                     .attr("transform",
                           "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        function make_x_axis() {
            return d3.svg.axis()
                 .scale(x)
                 .orient("bottom")
                 .ticks(10)
        }

        function make_y_axis() {
            return d3.svg.axis()
                     .scale(y)
                     .orient("left")
                     .ticks(4)
        }
        // Add Area
        svg.append("g")
                .append("path")
                .datum(data)
                .attr("class", "area")
                .attr("d", area(data));
        // Add the line
        svg.append("g")
               .attr("class", "path")
               .append("path")
               .attr("class", "line")
               .attr("d", valueline(data));
        //Add Grid
        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "grid")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(make_x_axis()
                     .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
                     .tickFormat("")
                );
        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "grid")
                .call(make_y_axis()
                         .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
                         .tickFormat("")
                 );
        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis)
                .selectAll("text").text(function (d, i) { return d = d + '.0 km'; }); //units toevoegen

        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .selectAll("text").text(function (d, i) { return d = d + ' m'; }); // units toevoegen 

        //Add Ruler
        var ruler = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "ruler")
                .style("display", "none");

        ruler.append("line")
                .style("stroke", "black")
                .style("stroke-width", "1")
                .style("pointer-events", "none")
                .attr("x0", 0)
                .attr("y0", 0)
                .attr("x1", 0)
                .attr("y1", height);

        //Add the event Rect
        svg.append("g")
                .attr("id", "grid")
                .append("rect")
                .attr("class", "event-rect")
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", 0)
                .attr("height", height)
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("style", "fill: transparent");

    }

    function parseTime(secs) {
        var t = new Date(1970, 0, 1);
        t.setSeconds(secs);
        var s = t.toTimeString().substr(0, 8);
        return s;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry this is so short, but I only have time to give it a quick once-over right now.

The first thing I noticed was the flickering of the cycling icon as I scroll through the bottom. Compared to the rest of the application, which looks great, this was awful.

This is happening because you are assigning the `Marker` to the `Map` on `mousemove`, which doesn't make much sense. If you move this initialisation to a `mouseover` handler instead, the flicker will be gone:

```
svg.select("#grid").on("mouseover", function() {
    ruler.style("display", null);
    marker.setMap(map);
}).on("mousemove", function() {
    var x = d3.mouse(this)[0];
    ruler.attr("transform", "translate(" + x + ", 0)");
    marker.setPosition(path[Math.floor((x / width) * path.length)]);
}).on("mouseout",  function() {
    ruler.style("display", none");
    marker.setMap(null);
});
```

You'll note that I got rid of `latlng` (didn't seem to add much value to me) and that I declared `x` as a local variable.

Comment: Thx for the quick response, Schism. This is a very good improvement. The flicker was indeed one of the things i wanted to solve. I updated the script on azure. Thx again